# fetch random number of records for one to many ralationship in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, fetch

I have two tables
table A is  village_info
table B is survey_info

village_info has fields
village_id and is_active

survey_info has fields
survey_id, survey_numbers, village_id, is_active

the relation in table is having one to many
i.e
each village has many  survey_numbers

quey using relationship

select
village_info.village_id,
survey_info.survey_numbers
from village_info
join
survey_info
on village_info.village_id = survey_info.village_id
where village_info.is_active =1 and survey_info.is_active=1;

my requirement is fetch 20 random survey_numbers for each village

here is my table structure

table A:village_info
village_id
1
2
3
4
5

table B:survey_info
survey_numbers  village_id
"12/3"       1
"7/3"            1
"23/4"           1
"44/5"           1
.            .
.            .
.            .

Requesting for optimised query to get random 20 survey_numbers for each village , i have list of village_id

I tried lots of thing using window functions and group by it is not so optimized and taking too much time  forever
the table has huge dataset more than 20 millions of survey numbers
i have deadline to give solution please do so need ful

the solution is appreciable waiting for response

Thanks & Regards
Ramesh

i have list of village_list = [village_id1, village_id2.......]

SELECT survey_number
FROM survey_info
WHERE village_id  in {[village_id1, village_id2.......] AND survey_meta.is_active = 1
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT

Comment: show what you tried with window functions?  not sure why you would use group by with those, but you don't show your desired output

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it with a window function:

```
select village_id, survey_numbers
from (
    select village_info.village_id, survey_info.survey_numbers,
        row_number() over (partition by village_info.village_id order by rand()) as rn
    from village_info
    join survey_info on village_info.village_id = survey_info.village_id
    where village_info.is_active=1 and survey_info.is_active=1
)
where rn <= 20
```

(If there are specific villages you want, add `and village_info.village_id in (...)` to the where clause of the subquery.)

Comment: I suspect that will still do a full table scan, plus more.

Comment: @RickJames unless they do have a list of villages they are interested in (question is ambiguous there), I don't see any way to avoid that, do you?